# generic long running background tasks in iPhone

Tags: iphone, background-process

After a cursory glance at the [Background Task Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) it seems a task must be one of the categories it describes. I'm creating an app that downloads and does a long running sync (maybe over 20 minutes long) task with an online resource. Can this be done using these APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can ask the system for more time to [complete a task](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW12) when your app moves to the background but the OS will kill your app if the task takes too long to complete. I believe the current limit is 10 minutes but that may change in future OS releases (or on future iOS devices).